# filtering subarrays with jsonpath

Tags: jsonpath

I using jsonpath to get some properties and list of properties of an objet.
For example, for this json I would like to get only the company name and the list of the first name of the staff :

```
{
  "companies": [
    {
      "name": "mycompany",
      "address": "not important here",
      "phone": "0123456789",
      "staff": [
        {
          "first_name": "ABC",
          "last_name": "def",
          "address": "not important here",
          "phone": "0123456789"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "GHI",
          "last_name": "klm",
          "address": "not important here",
          "phone": "0123456789"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "hiscompany",
      "address": "not important here",
      "phone": "0123456789",
      "staff": [
        {
          "first_name": "NOP",
          "last_name": "qrs",
          "address": "not important here",
          "phone": "0123456789"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like get only the following :

```
[{
  "name":"mycompany",
  "staff":["ABC", "GHI"]
},{
  "name":"hiscompany",
  "staff":["NOP"]
}
```

I have tried this expression :

```
$.companies[*]['name', 'staff']
```

But it returns the whole object, not only the first_name. Any idea how it can be done ?

Thanks